# from nav drawer fragment opened other activity how to reatain nav drawer fragment again with selected values

Tags: android

Designing an app

i have activity A (navigation drawer activity) in which i have X,Y,Z fragments i can navigate from them without any problem
but i want to navigate from fragment X to activity B and colect some data from user and again come back to fragment X with that data as well as the states of controls like switches textboxtx texts etc.

so far i have achieved the data sending from activity to fragment and opening nav drawer fragment from outside activity but states of control is not resumed its opening fresh activity with defaults.

Comment: try single instance of the activity

Comment: by using single instance i am getting activity resume. but it always resume until i close and reopen app.